# JSON response not objects from php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm using a php proxy to bypass cross domain ajax issues

My php:

```
return array(
        'status' => 'ok',
        'header' => $header,
        'content' => $content
    );
```

So now my $response['content'] holds my content, but i also want my headers.

If i:

```
echo $response['content'];
```

Then i get my response like:
[image]

Which is what i need! but i also want to have the $response[header] in the echo. 
But if i:

```
echo $response;
```

I get:
[image]

How can I get both in a json response so i can then use it in my javascript code?
And why is it just returning plaintext 'Array'

If i use json_encode its not formatted properly like in my first example.

[image]

Its lost all its formatting..?

Comment: `echo` does not print out objects. Perhaps use `var_dump` instead.

Comment: JSON_FORCE_OBJECT doesn't work either

Comment: use `json_encode()` maybe?

Comment: I said in OP i use json_encode and it looses its formatting. var_dump also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the respond data `$content` with `json_decode()`

```
$data = array(
    'status' => 'ok',
    'header' => $header,
    'content' => json_decode($content)
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Alternatively you can return JSON directly, without parsing

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{"status":"ok", "header":"' . $header . '", "content":"' . $content . '"}';
```

Comment: I don't normally upvote code-only answers, but I'm feeling generous. Try to explain *why* this code might work better than the OP's, so that they and future readers can learn how you worked it out, not just copy and paste your code.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be what i was looking for. Except my 'header' needs parsing to json now as its just an array of header 'text' e.g. "Pragma: no-cache"